# Android viewpager set background programmatically

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

I would like to know how to set a ViewPager background programmatically? In xml I can manually set the background like this: `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"`. I am getting a uri from a `SQLite` database and converting it to a `Bitmap`. I want to set that `Bitmap` as the background. Is this possible?

Comment: The only options are `viewPager.setBackground + viewPager.setBackgroundResource + viewPager.setBackgroundDrawable`. None of those accept Bitmap as a parameter. Something like `setImageResource` would have been useful, but since that only applies to an ImageView, it's not of much use. Just thought of something. I could probably put my viewPager and a Imageview in a relative layout, and just have the `imageview match_parent`. Should work @blackbelt

Comment: I think the solution from Tarsem could suit you needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**try**
first convert bitmap to drawable like

`Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmapobject);`

than 
use

```
 setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: setBackgroundDrawable() has been deprecated and setBackground() has taken its place.

Comment: Thanx ;) Will use setBackground() as well